# Locate a phrase, copy the row and then locate non-empy cell above and paste the lot onto a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi forum and thanks for looking at hopefully helping me with this challenge.

I'm receiving raw data from some software that I need to filter and create a report on.

So, here's a capture of the raw data:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/n3wZZGC.jpg]

So what I'm trying todo is to write VBA to find the phrase 'Volume Synthetic Full Backup' then copy the entire row (highlighted in yellow) onto a new sheet then scan column A upwards to the first non-empty cell it finds (bold text) and paste that onto the new sheet mentioned above so the output would look like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1TkaNon.jpg]

And then rinse and repeat for the rest of the sheet

Any takers? Beer is on offer and lots of it!

Sorry, am building it on the following:

```
Sub Save7()
Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
Sheet1.Range("B14:I14").Copy
Sheet3.Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Am using the following as a base and trying to build on it:

Comment: Sub Save7()
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Sheet1.Range("B14:I14").Copy
    Sheet3.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: don't put your code in comments, edit Q instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to stretch my skills  :)  This loops through column B until it is empty, and remembers what the last non blank column A entry was.  Sorry if it's not pretty.  Feel free to help me learn how to do it better!

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("b1").Select
    sheet3counter = 0
    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)) Then
            SectionName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "Volume Synthetic Full Backup" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheet3.Activate
            Range("a1").Offset(sheet3counter, 0).Select
            With Selection
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Value = SectionName
            End With
            Sheet1.Activate
            sheet3counter = sheet3counter + 1
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    'Tidy up and format Sheet3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("a1").Select
    Sheet3.Activate
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("a1").Select
End Sub
```

Where are we meeting for beer?

Comment: OMG! That works perfectly. I was focusing too much on the loop through for column A and bloating the macro. 

You sir are an official genius in my eyes and should you be in Cardiff at any point you'll find your favourite beverage raining down on you! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a great macro guy, but here is a high level thought on how to accomplish this:

- loop through column A, copying the value from the previous row if it's blank
- loop though column B looking for "Volume Synthetic Full Backup" and copy the entire row to new sheet when found

This saves you having to try to find the previous column A entry, which is where I think you're getting stuck.